# Column format separation using paste and an array

Tags: bash, rhel

Using bash for this script. I'm trying to display values of a disk by gathering the information and outputting them using paste. Sometimes a single physical volume may be assigned to multiple logical volumes. The output of that when using paste comes out a little funky.

Here is the function I created.

```
function ShowVolumeAttr()
{
    local lun_id="$1"

    # Show info on PV, VG, and LV
    PV=$(pvscan | grep $lun_id | awk '{print $2}')
    VG=$(pvscan | grep $lun_id | awk '{print $4}')
    declare -a LV
    for pv in $PV
    do
        LV[${#LV[@]}]+=$(pvdisplay -m $pv | grep "Logical volume" | awk '{print $3}')
    done
    echo -e "Physical Volume(s)\tVolume Group\tLogical Volume(s)"
    echo -e "------------------\t------------\t-----------------"
    paste <(printf %s "$PV") <(printf "\t%s" "$VG") <(printf "\t%s" "${LV[@]}")
}
```

And here is what the output looks like. I was hoping to have all of the Logical Volume entries line up under each other, but since it each entry after the 1st in the array gets its own line and there is no PV/VG in front of it, it tabs normally from the left side. Is there any way to line them up?

```
Physical Volume(s)      Volume Group    Logical Volume(s)
------------------      ------------    -----------------
/dev/sda2               rhel            /dev/rhel/root
                /dev/rhel/var
                /dev/rhel/home
                /dev/rhel/swap
                /dev/rhel/usr
                /dev/rhel/tmp
                /dev/rhel/opt
                /dev/rhel/var
```

Thanks,

Patrick

Tried to separate them out with different printf commands as well. Also tried adding tabs to the last printf entry.

EDIT

Ended up doing the below and it comes out looking nice. Kept playing with it over the last couple of days.

```
for pv in $PV
    do
        PVARRAY[${#PVARRAY[@]}]+=$pv
    done

    # Stack Overflow Addition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77928800/column-format-separation-using-paste-and-an-array
    for pv in "${PVARRAY[@]}"
    do
        # Add Logical Volumes for $pv into the array
        LV[${#LV[@]}]+=$(pvdisplay -m $pv | grep "Logical volume" | awk '{print $3}')

        # Loop through array and display contents
        for lv in "${!LV[@]}"
        do
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "Physical Volume(s)" "Volume Group" "Logical Volume(s)" "LV Size"
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "------------------" "------------" "-----------------" "-------"
            if [ "$lv" -ne 0 ]
            then
                printf "No physical volumes"
            fi

            PHYSV=$(lvs --segments ${LV[$lv]} -o+lv_size,devices | tail -n +2 | grep $pv | awk '{print $8}' | sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" | tr -d '()')
            #echo -e "PHYSV: $PHYSV"
            LOGVOL=$(pvs $pv -o+lv_path,devices | grep ${LV[$lv]}  | awk '{print $8}')
            #echo -e "LOGVOL: $LOGVOL"
            PHYSVOL=$(lvs --segments ${LV[$lv]} -o+lv_size,devices | tail -n +2 | grep $pv | awk '{print $6}')
            #echo -e "PHYSVOL: $PHYSVOL"
            VOLGRP=$(lvs --segments ${LV[$lv]} -o+lv_size,devices | tail -n +2 | grep $pv | awk '{print $2}')
            #echo -e "VOLGRP: $VOLGRP"

            paste <(printf "%s" "$PHYSV") <(printf "%s" "$VOLGRP") <(printf "%s" "${LV[$lv]}") <(printf "%s" "$PHYSVOL")
        done | column -ts $'\t'

        # Clear array
        LV=()
    done
```

Couple of different tests:

```
[root@lavulc01-new scripts]# ./dmcli.sh -l sdb
Partition /dev/sdb1 exists but there are no physical volumes found!
[root@lavulc01-new scripts]# ./dmcli.sh -l sda
Physical Volume(s)  Volume Group  Logical Volume(s)  LV Size
------------------  ------------  -----------------  -------
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/root     8.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/var      8.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/home     8.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/swap     32.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/usr      8.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/tmp      16.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/opt      8.00g
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/var      4.00m
Physical Volume(s)  Volume Group  Logical Volume(s)  LV Size
------------------  ------------  -----------------  -------
/dev/sda3           rhel          /dev/rhel/var      <92.00g
[root@lavulc01-new scripts]# ./dmcli.sh -l mpatha
Physical Volume(s)   Volume Group  Logical Volume(s)   LV Size
------------------   ------------  -----------------   -------
/dev/mapper/mpatha1  u01_vg        /dev/u01_vg/u01_lv  <1.50t


LUN mpatha ID: 60:06:01:60:5e:26:47:00:96:82:74:5b:0b:5b:2c:8c


Adapters Paths  Backing Disk    Array Port UUID
--------------  ------------    -----------------------
8:0:2:0                  sdz    50:06:01:61:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:2:0                  sdj    50:06:01:60:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:3:0                  sdn    50:06:01:62:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:3:0                 sdad    50:06:01:63:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:0:0                  sdb    50:06:01:68:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:1:0                  sdf    50:06:01:6a:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:0:0                  sdr    50:06:01:69:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:1:0                  sdv    50:06:01:6b:47:e4:45:bd
[root@lavulc01-new scripts]# ./dmcli.sh -l mpatha1
Disk mpatha1 not found or is a partition device.
[root@lavulc01-new scripts]# ./dmcli.sh -l mpathd
  Failed to find device for physical volume "/dev/mapper/mpathd?".


LUN mpathd ID: 60:06:01:60:99:10:47:00:91:b9:c0:5c:8e:e3:29:86


Adapters Paths  Backing Disk    Array Port UUID
--------------  ------------    -----------------------
7:0:2:3                  sdm    50:06:01:60:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:3:3                  sdq    50:06:01:62:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:2:3                 sdac    50:06:01:61:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:3:3                 sdag    50:06:01:63:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:1:3                  sdi    50:06:01:6a:47:e4:45:bd
7:0:0:3                  sde    50:06:01:68:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:0:3                  sdu    50:06:01:69:47:e4:45:bd
8:0:1:3                  sdy    50:06:01:6b:47:e4:45:bd
```

Comment: `paste` is only useful if there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between the lines in the inputs. If not, you'll need to write your own code to display the related information properly. Maybe you can use `join`, or you might have to code it explicitly with `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using `column` rather than `paste`.  Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pv="/dev/sda2"
vg="rhel"
declare -a lv
lv=(/dev/rhel/root /dev/rhel/var /dev/rhel/home /dev/rhel/swap /dev/rhel/usr /dev/rhel/tmp /dev/rhel/opt /dev/rhel/var)

for i in "${!lv[@]}"; do
  if [ "$i" -eq 0 ] ; then
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "Physical Volume(s)" "Volume Group" "Logical Volume(s)"
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "------------------" "------------" "-----------------"
  fi
  if [ "$i" -ne 0 ] ; then
    pv=" "; vg=" "
  fi
  printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t\n" "$pv" "$vg" "${lv[$i]}"
done | column -ts $'\t'
```

Results in output:

```
Physical Volume(s)  Volume Group  Logical Volume(s)
------------------  ------------  -----------------
/dev/sda2           rhel          /dev/rhel/root
                                  /dev/rhel/var
                                  /dev/rhel/home
                                  /dev/rhel/swap
                                  /dev/rhel/usr
                                  /dev/rhel/tmp
                                  /dev/rhel/opt
                                  /dev/rhel/var
```